# Checking password match returns "Passwords match" when both fields are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords

I'm making a registration form and I want to check if the user has matching passwords while he's typing and give him the appropriate message. So far everything works, except for these things:

- When the user deletes everything from Confirm Password field it still
  gives him a message "Passwords do not match" while I want to give him
  no message or a message saying "Please confirm password".
- When the
  user deletes everything from both fields, it gives him a message
  "Passwords match", while it should give him no message at all.

Here's my code:

```
$(function () {
   $("#txtNewPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
   $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});


function checkPasswordMatch() {
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("");
    var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

    if (password == "" && confirmPassword == ""){
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("");
        $("#divIsPasswordExist").html("");
    }
    else if (password != "" && confirmPassword == "") {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("");
    }

    else if (password == "" && confirmPassword != "")
        $("#divIsPasswordExist").html("Password cannot be empty!");
    else
        $("#divIsPasswordExist").html("");


    if (password != confirmPassword)
    {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").removeClass("registrationFormConfirm");
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").addClass("registrationFormAlert");
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").removeClass("registrationFormAlert");
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").addClass("registrationFormConfirm");
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
    }
}
```

Any ideas, please?
Thank you!

Comment: I think `return` helps you lot for give proper message and return from that particular place rather than executing whole code.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you might be interested in detecting the HTML5 [`onInput`](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput) event instead of `onKeyUp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
......
        if (password == "" && confirmPassword == ""){
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("");
            $("#divIsPasswordExist").html("Password and Confirm Password dosen't exists");
            return;
        }
        else if (password != "" && confirmPassword == "") {
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Confirm Password dosent't exists");
            return;
        }
        else if (password == "" && confirmPassword != ""){
            $("#divIsPasswordExist").html("Password cannot be empty!");
            return;
        }
        else{
            $("#divIsPasswordExist").html("");
        }
        if (password != confirmPassword)
        {
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").removeClass("registrationFormConfirm");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").addClass("registrationFormAlert");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").removeClass("registrationFormAlert");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").addClass("registrationFormConfirm");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
        }
.........
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `if (password != confirmPassword)` is false, because both are empty anyway, when you set the `var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();` and `var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();` these both equal each other. You should add a return after you check if the values are empty, so that way when the user deletes the text, it won't check anything below the first check statement.

//first check

```
if (password == "" && confirmPassword == ""){
return false;
}
```

... rest of code

Answer (score 1):

```
if (password == "" && confirmPassword == ""){
    return false;
}
    ....
    ....

if(confirmPassword != "")
    $("#txtConfirmPassword").html("Please confirm password");

        if (password != confirmPassword)
        {
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").removeClass("registrationFormConfirm");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").addClass("registrationFormAlert");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").removeClass("registrationFormAlert");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").addClass("registrationFormConfirm");
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
        }

 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more elegant way to do this. Change your conditions to this

```
if(password.length > 0 && confirmPassword.length >0) {
    if(password == confirmPassword) {
        //confirmed
    } else {
       // not confirm
    }

} else {
   //not entered
}
```